# repo : checking out source code from existing .repo directory without additional download

Tags: git, repo

I've copied a .repo directory from one of the desktops and I want to checkout the complete source code.

Now how do I checkout the entire source code without using "repo sync" command ?

I have previously downloaded the code using the following command

```
repo init -u <URL>  -b <x> -m <tag> --repo-url=git://xxx/repo.git
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `repo sync --local-only` is doing job for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid networking, I think there is nothing more than:

```
repo forall -c git checkout <tag>
```

Comment: Not working. It says "skipping xyz/abc". I am using one of the tags in "https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP/release", under "Tag / Build ID" column